# Full-join after goruping dataframe in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------+---------------+----+
| period |     label     | n  |
+--------+---------------+----+
|      4 | Engaged       |  2 |
|      4 | Remarkable    |  1 |
|      5 | Engaged       |  1 |
|      5 | Inconsistent  |  2 |
|      5 | Remarkable    |  5 |
|      6 | Engaged       |  1 |
|      6 | Inconsistent  |  1 |
|      6 | Remarkable    |  5 |
|      7 | Engaged       |  2 |
|      7 | Remarkable    |  3 |
|      7 | Transactional |  2 |
+--------+---------------+----+
```

And I need to make it such that every option for label (`Inconsistent, Transactional, Engaged, Remarkable`) is present for every period.  And if every label is not used in each period, then it should be inserted for that period with the value of `n` equal to 0.

I thought about pivoting the dataframe from long-to-wide, and then filling in missing values with 0, but sometimes every value might not be see in any of the periods.  I also thought about grouping the dataframe by period and then doing a full join to all the labels, but it seems that groups are ignored when joining a dataframe.

I need to end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------+---------------+----+
| period |     label     | n  |
+--------+---------------+----+
|      4 | Inconsistent  |  0 |
|      4 | Transactional |  0 |
|      4 | Engaged       |  2 |
|      4 | Remarkable    |  1 |
|      5 | Inconsistent  |  2 |
|      5 | Transactional |  0 |
|      5 | Engaged       |  1 |
|      5 | Remarkable    |  5 |
|      6 | Inconsistent  |  1 |
|      6 | Transactional |  0 |
|      6 | Engaged       |  1 |
|      6 | Remarkable    |  5 |
|      7 | Inconsistent  |  0 |
|      7 | Transactional |  2 |
|      7 | Engaged       |  2 |
|      7 | Remarkable    |  3 |
+--------+---------------+----+
```

Here is the example data that I am working with:

```
df <- as.data.frame(
  list(
    period = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
                  7L, 7L, 7L),
    label = c(
      "Engaged",
      "Remarkable",
      "Engaged",
      "Inconsistent",
      "Remarkable",
      "Engaged",
      "Inconsistent",
      "Remarkable",
      "Engaged",
      "Remarkable",
      "Transactional"
    ),
    n = c(2L, 1L, 1L,
          2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L)
  )
)

options <- as.data.frame(
  list(
    label = c(
      "Inconsistent",
      "Transactional",
      "Engaged",
      "Remarkable"
    ),
    n = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can group by 'period', and then `complete` the 'label' based on the values of 'label' from 'options' dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(period) %>%
     complete(label = options$label, fill = list(n = 0))
```